# jQuery Countdown doesn't update when inside jQuery content switcher/slider/swapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown, jquery-countdown

I'm using [this jQuery countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) inside of 2 content divs using [this switcher plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-content-panel-switcher/). It all works fairly well except for that the countdowns don't constantly update inside of the divs. You have to switch back and forth between them to get an updated countdown.

I think it may have [something to do with this](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-content-panel-switcher/wiki/Using_Other_Plugins_With_JCPS) but I'm not sure and having trouble figuring out how to do that with the countdown plugin.

Here is the JS:

```
$(function () {
$('#count-na').countdown( 
    {until: $.countdown.UTCDate(-4, 2013, 06-1, 9)});
});
$(function () {
$('#count-eu').countdown( 
    {until: $.countdown.UTCDate(-0, 2013, 06-1, 14)});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
jcps.fader(200, '#switcher-panel');
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="switcher-panel"></div>
    <div id="na-content" class="switcher-content show">
        <div id="count-na"></div>
        <div class="subtext">until something happens</div>
    </div>
    <div id="eu-content" class="switcher-content">
        <div id="count-eu"></div>
        <div class="subtext">until something happens</div>
    </div>
    <a id="na" class="switcher">North America</a> - <a id="eu" class="switcher">Europe</a>
</div>
```

And finally  a JSFiddle if it's not quite clear: http://jsfiddle.net/tCyBm/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding onTick : watchCountdown?
Yeah. I just checked out the documentation for ya. first I want to point out if you are using IE and not running the most recent version of the API then that is your problem.
Second, try taking your function calls out of your anonymous function because it may be effecting the way it communicates with the countdown.js

The onTick : watchCountdown shouldn't be necessary but

```
     $('#count-eu').countdown(
       {until: $.countdown.UTCDate(-0, 2013, 06-1, 14), onTick: watchCountdown});

    function watchCountdown(periods) {  $('#monitor').text('Just ' + periods[5] +
       ' minutes and ' + periods[6] + ' seconds to go');}
```

A callback function that is invoked each time the 
countdown updates itself. Within the function this refers to 
the division that holds the widget. The array of current countdown
 periods (int[7] - based on the format setting) is passed as a parameter:
 [0] is years, [1] is months, [2] is weeks, [3] is days, [4] is hours, [5]
 is minutes, and [6] is seconds.  ///i copied that part right from the documentation.

Let me know how that works, I am trying to build my street cred around these parts so I will figure it out.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?